# Django: Trouble redirecting to previous page after cancel editing

Tags: python, django, primary-key

I'm working on a blog project where it shows all the posts of a blog on home page. I have an edit function for each blog entry and contains two options: publish and cancel.

this is what my form looks like

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text',)
```

In views.py it looks like this:

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

In html it looks like this:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Edit post</h1>

    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" >Publish</button>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=? %}">Cancel</a>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.post_remove, name='post_remove'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$', views.add_comment, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.comment_edit, name='comment_edit'),
]
```

I could'n figure out what's the pk in html. I have tried pk and post.pk but either works. Anyone can help. Thanks

Comment: Where is the form you're trying to access in your templates through the piece of code `{{ form.as_p }}` ?
You have to send it through your views. Also use a context dict() to solve your "pk" problem. Again you're not sending it(pk) from your views.

Comment: try out `post.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there isn't a form object that you're sending to your html, so in your code,

`{{ form.as_p }}` 
wouldn't work. Regarding accessing the "pk" value inside the template, you have to send it through your context dict().

Now that you've told about the form class,

Try this,

```
#Import the form from forms.py
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    form = PostForm()
    context = {'post' : post , 'pk' : pk , 'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)
```

And the template should look like,

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Edit post</h1>

<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" >Publish</button>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=pk %}">Cancel</a>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Note** : I don't know why you're trying to send "Post" model object to the templates. But still I kept it in the code.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This template was originally used for both creating a new post and editing one. As I'd like to add more functions to each one I just separate the templates but still use the same format. I tried your code but still don't work, got this error msg"NoReverseMatch          Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']"

Comment: Also if i change the url in href="{% url 'post_detail' pk %}" to any other ones that dont need a pk it works fine.

Comment: Can you show me your urls.py? and why are you putting `href="{% url 'post_detail' pk %}` inside the anchor tag for cancel option?

Comment: Sure I have updated in the main post. I wanted to put a button at first but somehow the cancel button acted as a publish button as well. I couldn't figure it out so i just add an anchor tag to redirect the page

Comment: @ShivamSharma `post.id` will be pk no need to supply pk in the context.

Comment: @RajanChahan yes absolutely. The question was slightly incomplete and I didn't know why the "post" model was being sent to the templates in the first place. But the current problem is weird. `href="{% url 'post_detail' pk %}` has always worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. i realized i was looking at the wrong piece of code, but you're right it's about context dict(). the pk was undefined because i didn't pass it to the form. I added context = {'post' : post , 'pk' : pk , 'form' : form} in another function and it works now.

Comment: also as Rajan said above, the instance post also has the attribute id. So you can access the pk through "pk=post.id" rather than "pk=pk" in templates as well... Hope this all helps.. Thanks.